# Как создать многострочный компонент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется такой компонент

```
function Person(props){
  return (
    <div>Name: {props.name} {props.surname}</div>
    <div>Age: {props.age}</div>
  );
}
```

При рендеринге он не появляется.

```
const element = <Person name="Иван" surname="Иванович" age="47"></Person>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Но когда оставляем один блок - все работает

```
function Person(props){
  return <div>Name: {props.name} {props.surname}</div>;
}
```

Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если реакт достаточно новый, то надо использовать [фрагменты](//reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). А если старый, то никак.

```js
function Person(props) {
  return <React.Fragment>
    <div>Name: {props.name} {props.surname}</div>
    <div>Age: {props.age}</div>
  </React.Fragment>
}

const element = <Person name="Иван" surname="Иванович" age="47"></Person>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<section id="app"></section>
```

По идее, для фрагментов должен быть доступен более короткий синтаксис, но в сниппете он не заработал (возможно, бабель устарел):

```
function Person(props) {
  return <>
    <div>Name: {props.name} {props.surname}</div>
    <div>Age: {props.age}</div>
  </>
}
```

Comment: Здесь каким то образом это работает без фрагментов https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Нет там такого. Покажи.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components

Comment: Или это что то другое?

Comment: Там один корневой элемент (div): https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjuXp.png А ты хочешь без него. В таком случае надо использовать фрагмент или массив.

Comment: Даже если я так делаю все равно ничего не получается

Comment: Всё получается.

Comment: <> </> это и есть фрагмент просто более удобная запись

Comment: @Vasujke, я знаю.